# How to customise the UI after a user is signed in using <Authenticator> (aws amplify pre-built Auth component)

Tags: react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm trying to use aws-amplify [authenticator](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react-native#using-the-authenticator-component)for my app. My idea is to show the app first (that's the reason why i didn't wrap the whole app into withAuthenticator) and if user needs to sign in they will be led to a authentication screen, which is like below:

```
import { Authenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native'
const AuthScreen =({ route }) => {

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Authenticator>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.goBack()
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>go back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </Authenticator>
    </View>
  )
}

export default AuthScreen;
```

however in this way once the user is signed in, the UI will display like below, with a string and a signout button:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQd6P.png)

My question is how can i hide this string and display the info i want after user is signed in? i tried to make a CustomSignOut component, add it in  but it didn't work (didn't override):

```
<CustomSignOut override={'SignIn'}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok finally finally figured this out... use hideDefault={true} in , then add all the other components except for Greetings (includes signout button) and TOTPSetup (somehow it just didn't work when adding it on), and the signout button & the string will disappear